# Flutter Error: A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' when get value form function Future<bool>

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, future, getvalue

I met problem when get value form function Future
I have a function below

```
Future<bool> checkstr(String str) async {
     bool result = await check(str);
     if (result == null) {
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
}
```

when i get and check value met error

```
Expanded(
      child: model.isBusy
           ? CircularProgressIndicator()
           : ListView.builder(   
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                          model.checkstr(str)       //<------ error this line
                          ? title: Text('true')
                          : title: Text('false'),
                    }),
          ),
```

error

```
 Flutter Error: A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'
```

please help me.

Comment: You cannot call the method directly cause you need await the result. Try make the method not future or do the call in another place and wait the result before using the value.

Comment: Post your `check(str)` function. Is it a future? Why are you waiting for it? Based on your answer, you have one of two solutions mainly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `FutureBuilder` since `checkstr()` is a **future**

```
Expanded(
    child: model.isBusy
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return FutureBuilder(
              future: checkstr(str),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data ? 'true' : 'false'));
              },
            );
          }));
```